# Widget dragging not working when hovering over the widget itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm having an issue where I have implemented a dragging feature for widgets using `eventFilter()`, but it seems when I drag towards the right and my cursor hovers over the widget which in my case is a `QPushButton` it seems to stop tracking until I hover out of the widget

[image]

How would I fix this?

```py
class widget1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.widget = QPushButton("button0", self)



class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.createbutton = QPushButton('+', self)
        self.createbutton.setGeometry(5, 5, 15, 15)
        self.createbutton.clicked.connect(self.createWidget)



        self.show()


    def createWidget(self):

        self.new_widget = widget1()
        self.new_widget.setParent(self)
        self.new_widget.show()
        self.new_widget.installEventFilter(self)


    def eventFilter(self, source, event):

        if event.type() == QEvent.MouseMove:

            MousePos = QPoint(event.pos())

            if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:

                source.move(source.x() + MousePos.x(), source.y() + MousePos.y())



        return super(MainWindow, self).eventFilter(source, event)
```

Basically I have a class with a widget in it called `widget1()` (*This will be my custom widget in the future*) I am then adding it dynamically to the window every time I press `self.createbutton` using `.show()` instead of using a layout, then it installs the event filter to it so that it can allow for dragging.

Answer (score 1):

The event filter is receiving events for the widget1 instance but not for its child widgets (i.e. the QPushButton). A quick fix is to invoke `QMouseEvent.ignore` for the QPushButton's `mouseMoveEvent` so the mouse event will be propagated up to the parent widget and received in the event filter.

```
class widget1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.widget = QPushButton("button0", self)
        self.widget.mouseMoveEvent = lambda event: event.ignore()
```